# How to parse date string which includes T

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I'm new to javascript but I want to parse this date.

**2019-03-04T06:20:30.000**

How can I do this?

`Date.parse()`or `new Date()` not works for this format.

Should I have to change this into string and use regular expression?

Comment: What format do you want the date? ie. expected result?

Comment: `Date.parse()` and `new Date()` should both work. What are you expecting this date to be? As an ISO date this represents 4th march.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually supported via javascript. Have a look at the code below.

```js
var dateString = "2019-03-04T06:20:30.000";

var dateObject = new Date(dateString);

alert(dateObject);
```

Comment: OP says `new Date() not works for this format.`?

Comment: You can't trust anybody ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.toLocaleDateString()`

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-03-04T06:20:30.000').toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
console.log(new Date('2019-03-04T06:20:30.000').toString('en-GB'));
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote?

Comment: `toLocaleDateString()` isn't parsing anything here. and OP has already stated that *"new Date() not works for this format."*

Comment: Have you tried running the snippet? This is the standard functionality in javascript. If it doesn't work, then the OP is doing something else wrong. But the answer is not incorrect. @OlayinkaO here, have my upvote

Comment: I don't disagree but re-iterating what the OP already knows doesn't actually answer the question. It's a bad question, adding bad answers doesn't help. Anyway it's closed now